# Eclipse m2e "Update Maven Project" adds an unneeded bin directory

Tags: eclipse, m2e

I encounter a strange behavior of m2e on eclipse:

1. Clone project from remote git repository
2. The dir structure showed at project explorer does not have maven natures, only pom.xml at root and packages. No "JRE System Library", no "Maven dependencies". No "src/main/java", only "my.packages.1", "my.packages.2"
3. I update the project using maven->Update Maven Project. Everything displays well, except one "bin" directory created and the content of bin dir is the same as what i checkout from git.

example: 
before update maven project:

```
.settings/
src/
pom.xml
.gitignore
```

after update maven project:

```
.settings/
src/
pom.xml
.gitignore
bin/  <------ this dir appears after update maven project
bin/.settings/  <----------- contents the same as outside dir
bin/src
bin/.gitignore
bin/pom.xml
```

How should I avoid this strange behavior?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems, that before you did the "update project", the `bin` dir was configured as output directory. Output directories are hidden by default in Eclipse (at least in Package Explorer and Project Explorer). When you configured the project as Maven project, the output directory was changed to `target/classes`. Your bin folder is now just another folder, which isn't hidden any more.
Since you don't need it anymore, you can safely delete it.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Is there any ways to set project default to maven project?

Comment: Not that i know. But you can import the project as Maven project, then it will be correctly configured on import. For this, go to the menu File -> Import -> Maven -> Existing Maven projects

Answer (score 2):

It happened to me as well because I excluded the `.classpath` from the repo in `.gitignore`.  I initially thought there could be some conflicts between windows and linux developers but I was wrong, `.classpath` should be identical.

If you don't have a `.classpath`, upon cloning, java builder kicks in and messes things up before maven builder recreates a clean `.classpath`.

Conclusion, commit and push the `.classpath` and this does not happen anymore.

Comment: No this is not the solution. IDE specific files should not be commited. Especially when you work in a multi-IDE environment...

Comment: @Lonzak, In practice, there aren't that many IDEs on the market. Some folks here use eclipse, others idea. Never experienced any collision. (.project, .idea, .settings, etc).
Principles are nice, but have a cost. Some folks, like me, prefer to be pragmatic.

Comment: My point was not the collision between IDEs but those files are completely irrelevant for other IDEs. I use eclipse and don't want to be bothered we intellij files or netbeans or others. The pragmatic solution for us was to not comit these files and to comit only "project" relevant files. And by the way besides the 3 main IDEs there are lots of [others](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/what-will-be-the-best-java-ides-in-2020/) ;-)